# How to upload a Sencha App to the iTunes platform?

Tags: iphone, ios, sencha-touch, info.plist

I have an app developed in Sencha which is developed by someone else. It's completed app I just want to upload this on iTunes. I am using a Mac.

Questions are:

- How to open the App in Xcode.
- I want to set info.plist file and Entitlement File.
- How can I build .ipa file of this for upload.

Is there separate folders for iOS, Android, Windows like that to choose ?

Comment: Have you read the manual of Sencha?

Comment: This isn't a specific programming related question but rather a framework "getting started" question. See [this documentation](http://www.sencha.com/learn/getting-started-with-sencha-touch-2).

Comment: I solved it out :[here](http://mobitick.blogspot.in/2012/11/installing-sencha-on-mac-osx.html?showComment=1370614921341#c7154270245567946977)

Answer (score 2):

#### For uploading your app to Appstore:

- Use the Sencha SDK to build the app. This will generate a .app file
- Drag and drop the generated .app file into iTunes
- Drag the app from iTunes back out to your file system. This will generate a .ipa file, suitable for uploading to the App Store (No, I am *not* making this up)
- Log into iTunes Connect
- Click on Manage your Applications
- Click on Add New App
- Enter info for your App
- Open XCode
- Select XCode > Open Developer Tool > Application Loader
- Click Deliver Your App
- Select the app that you defined in iTunes Connect
- Select the .ipa file for upload
- The app will be uploaded to Apple for review.

Refer [Submitting a sencha touch app](http://druckit.wordpress.com/2012/04/23/submitting-a-sencha-touch-2-native-app-to-the-app-store-8/) for details.

Read [Sencha](http://www.sencha.com/learn/getting-started-with-sencha-touch-2), it'll answer your other questions.

Comment: Thanks @Midhun I am trying .....